# Dynamic webservice client and java reflection

Tags: java, web-services, reflection, wsdl

Webservice contains:

```
ResultObj resultObj = getDocCountAction(RequestObj requestObj);
```

where:

```
ResultObj and RequestObj contain "Long count" attribute.
```

so, the webservis method gets count on input and returns count on output (I know - it's nonsense :)

I want for "client.invoke("getDocCountAction", requestObj);" to return value to responseObj. By default it returns Object[].

```
// webservice client from remote wsdl
String wsdlURL = "http://localhost:8080/test/test.wsdl"
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
DynamicClientFactory factory = DynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = factory.createClient(wsdlURL, loader);

// accessing request object and setter method for count attribute and setting 666 value
Object requestObj = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("pl.kago.stuff.RequestObj").newInstance();
Method setCount = requestObj.getClass().getMethod("setCount", Long.class);
setCount.invoke(requestObj, 666);
```

and now I have problem. I know I must invoke webservice method and define and acces responseObj. **How to "bind" result of webmethod with responseObj?**

```
// accessing response object and getter method for count attribute
Object responseObj = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() .loadClass("pl.kago.stuff.ResponseObj").newInstance();
Method getCount = responseObj.getClass().getMethod("getCount", Long.class);
client.invoke("getCount", responseObj);
```

below access to webmethod

```
Object[] result = client.invoke("getCountAction", requestObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

heh :)

For others with this kind of problem:

```
// webservice client from remote wsdl
String wsdlURL = "http://localhost:8080/test/test.wsdl"
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
DynamicClientFactory factory = DynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = factory.createClient(wsdlURL, loader);

// accessing request object and setter method for count attribute and setting 666 value
Object requestObj = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("pl.kago.stuff.RequestObj").newInstance();
Method setCount = requestObj.getClass().getMethod("setCount", Long.class);
setCount.invoke(requestObj, 666);

// "binding" new result object to webmethod result
Object responseObj = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() .loadClass("pl.kago.stuff.ResponseObj").newInstance();
responseObj = client.invoke("getCountAction", requestObj);

// getting count value
Method getCount = responseObj .getClass().getMethod("getCount");
Object count = getCount.invoke(responseObj);
```